# Input Dispatching issue ANR reports in Unity 3D Game on Android platform

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-anr-dialog

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 18. Wait queue head age: 5610.0ms.) com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity #

I am facing some issues related to `ANR` from last 4 to 5 months.
The below issues first came in `Unity 5.6.3` then I upgraded the unity to `Unity 2017.3.0` but the issues are still there. I figured something out on monitor logs that the input dispatching message came whenever an ad was displayed.

I have tested my game on multiple android devices and no ANR was displayed.

**The error message:**

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7465c258 self=0xb8398be0
 | sysTid=10998 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fafb34
 | state=S schedstat=( 1505944507 1531448513 2742 ) utm=105 stm=45 core=3 >HZ=100
 | stack=0xbe7df000-0xbe7e1000 stackSize=8MB
 | held mutexes=

at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x09d2b43b> (a java.lang.Object)
at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:387)
at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu.zza (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkw.zza (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzji.zza (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zzhw (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjr$zza.zzhy (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjr.zza (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx.zza (unavailable)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd (unavailable)
at com.google.unity.ads.Interstitial$2.run (Interstitial.java:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616) .  "
```